# Issues with the Probability formula

Tags: probability

We have $ \mathbb P ( A \cup B) = \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(A \cap B)$

and $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = \mathbb P(A) \mathbb P(B)$.

These formulas work for one example but not for the other.

Example 1:

There are 10 girls and 20 boys, half of each are blue-eyed.

What is the probability that a chosen child is either a girl or is blue-eyed?

$\mathbb P(\text{girl}) = \frac{10}{30}$

$\mathbb P(\text{blue-eyed}) = \frac{15}{30}$

$\mathbb P(\text{girl and blue-eyed}) = \frac{10}{30}\cdot\frac{15}{30} = \frac 5{30}$

$\mathbb P(\text{girl or blue-eyed}) = \frac{10}{30}+\frac{15}{30}-\frac 5{30}$

All  is fine and correct. Why not for the following example:

Example 2:

Two dice are thrown. what is the probability for the sum to be $4$ or $6$?

$\mathbb P(\text{sum is $4$}) = \frac 3{36}$

$\mathbb P(\text{sum is $6$}) = \frac 5{36}$

$\mathbb P(\text{sum is $4$ and sum is $6$}) = ? $

We know that it cannot be $4$ and $6$ at the same time, so it is zero.

But the above formula gives $\mathbb P(\text{sum is $4$ and sum is $6$}) = \mathbb P(\text{sum is $4$})\mathbb P(\text{sum is $6$}) = \frac 3{36}\cdot\frac 5{36} = \text{not zero}$

What happened? Why does the product formula suddenly stop working in case of no overlap?

Wasn't the product formula supposed to be always true, so the formula should give a zero result?

Please explain.

Comment: The "product formula" only holds for independent events, it does not hold generally.  For instance, generally speaking $P(A\cap A)=P(A)\neq P(A)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The 'product formula' only works for independent events. That is, when the probability of $A$ has no bearing on the probability of $B$. To illustrate why, here is a slightly amusing example taken from *Why do Buses Come in Threes?*: the probability of getting heads when you flip a fair coin is $\frac{1}{2}$, and the probability of rolling a $6$ with a fair die is $\frac{1}{6}$. Notice that these two events are completely unrelated: if the coin lands on heads, then this does not affect the chance of me rolling a $6$ at all. Therefore, the probability of getting heads *and* rolling a $6$ is $\frac{1}{12}$.

Now consider this example: let's say the probability of a person walking down the street being a man is $\frac{1}{2}$. Also, the probability of a person walking down the street wearing a skirt is $\frac{1}{4}$. But the probability of a person walking down the street being a man wearing a skirt is not $\frac{1}{8}$! You may laugh, but the reason why this is the case is because one's gender has an effect on one's tendency to wear a skirt. Compare that with the coin/die example, and you have your answer.

NB the study of dependent events is closely linked with conditional probability. I'd highly recommend looking at [this website](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-events-conditional.html) for more information.